# Replace Chart.js Data during `onClick` causes _meta error

Tags: chart.js

Chart.js Version: 2.9.3

I have an experience I'm trying to create and based on what I'm seeing with click handling, it might not be (easily?) possible.

I have a bar chart. When users click a bar, they are "drilling" into that data. This is definitely doable from an interaction perspective, but there is a hangup.

**Problem Source**

[`handleEvent` calls the `onClick` handler](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.9.3/src/core/core.controller.js#L1085) (which would cause the drill down, changing the underlying dataset. `handleEvent` then attempts to [update the hoverstyle of me.active](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.9.3/src/core/core.controller.js#L1096). This results in an error during [`getDatasetMeta` when `datasetIndex` is out of bounds for the new dataset](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.9.3/src/core/core.controller.js#L850).

**Reproduction**

Here is [a reproduction](https://codepen.io/cromwellryan/pen/0fbd7ee16e9e4e01b0e0c9d6f84deaf3?editors=1010). You will see in the console the exception: `Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined`

**Some things I am considering:**

- Is there a nice way to have the drill down occur after the Chart.js click handling is fully complete?
- A PR to make `updateHoverStyle` [safe for getDatasetMeta misses](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.9.3/src/core/core.controller.js#L851).

Thoughts? Am I heading in a reasonable direction?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for better debugging this issue?

Comment: Added a reproduction to the question and here is a quick link for you @sandeepjoshi https://codepen.io/cromwellryan/pen/0fbd7ee16e9e4e01b0e0c9d6f84deaf3?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick by using `setTimeout` in your click handler:

```
onClick: () => {
    setTimeout(drilldownIntoRed);
},
```

Check it out:

```js
const labelsA = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
const datasetA = [{
    y: 12,
    x: "Red"
  },
  {
    y: 19,
    x: "Blue"
  },
  {
    y: 3,
    x: "Yellow"
  },
  {
    y: 5,
    x: "Green"
  },
  {
    y: 2,
    x: "Purple"
  },
  {
    y: 3,
    x: "Orange"
  }
];

const labelsADrilldown = ["Fav", "Like it", "Just OK"];
const datasetADrilldown = [{
    y: 3,
    x: "Fav Color"
  },
  {
    y: 7,
    x: "Like it"
  },
  {
    y: 2,
    x: "Just OK"
  },
]

const labelsB = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
const datasetB = [{
    y: 2,
    x: "Red"
  },
  {
    y: 7,
    x: "Blue"
  },
  {
    y: 4,
    x: "Yellow"
  },
  {
    y: 12,
    x: "Green"
  },
  {
    y: 1,
    x: "Purple"
  },
  {
    y: 8,
    x: "Orange"
  }
];

let mychart = null;

function go() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: labelsA,
      datasets: [{
          label: "Bear Votes",
          data: datasetA,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 29, 255, 0.5)"
        },
        {
          label: "Turtle Votes",
          data: datasetB,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 55, 0.5)"
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      onClick: () => {
        setTimeout(drilldownIntoRed);
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    }
  });
}

function drilldownIntoRed() {
  myChart.data = {
    labels: labelsADrilldown,
    datasets: [{
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: datasetADrilldown,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 29, 255, 0.5)"
    }]
  };

  myChart.update(0);
}

function reset() {
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.destroy();
  }
  go();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", go);
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", reset);
```

```css
.hint {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-QEiC894KVkN9Tsoi6+mKf8HaCLJvyA6QIRzY5KrfINXYuP9NxdIkRQhGq3BZi0J4I7V5SidGM3XUQ5wFiMDuWg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="width:300px;height: 300px">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
</div>
<p class="hint">Click a bar to drill down</p>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks  . This is what we ended up doing for the timer being, but it’s definitely a hack. .

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes we don't have any way to schedule something after current call stack unwinds, setTimeout come in handy!